# I wanted to set up my own webserver. Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql

I wanted to set up my own web server, but As I follow directions from this website https://www.linux.com/tutorials/easy-lamp-server-installation/ I couldn't download MySQL and have tried many different videos to install my web server and none of them work well. The method on this website came closest to what I could work with. so I want to know why Im getting this error so I can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you installed it from package, so the package is already installed (that's the easiest way + you avoid errors made during self-installation from sources)

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Does socket file `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` exist?

Is it server itsef running?

```
ps aux | grep [m]ysqld
```

Comment: I have successfully installed MySQL but when it is installed I couldn't use it because all the tutorials online show that when it is installed the command line will prompt me to set a password, but when I installed this it didn't, so as I use commands that the online tutorial use, it also asks me for a password except I have no idea what the password is.

Comment: how could I check if the socket file exist, because I don't have any understanding of command lines currently and is trying to learn.

Comment: @sandershi just `ls -la /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` :)